# Edit header text according to data stored on Mage::registry

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, adminhtml

I have all the necessary files and structures in order to handle CRUD operations on a table I have added on the database. On the `Edit.php` file I have the `getHeaderText()` function that modifies the header that will appear on the edit page when either modifying or adding new set of values to the table.

The problem I'm having is that when the following code is evaluated:

```
if (Mage::registry('allpages_data')  && Mage::registry('allpages_data')->getId())
```

It always return `NULL` so always shows *New reference* text on the header. Checked and when I'm editing it correctly edits the current set of values and when adding new it adds a new set. Tried several solutions and none worked.

**2nd EDIT**
Here is my `allpages_data` var_dump:

```
object(Dts_Allpages_Model_Referencedpages)[412]
  protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'core_abstract' (length=13)
  protected '_eventObject' => string 'object' (length=6)
  protected '_resourceName' => string 'allpages/referencedpages' (length=24)
  protected '_resource' => null
  protected '_resourceCollectionName' => string 'allpages/referencedpages_collection' (length=35)
  protected '_cacheTag' => boolean false
  protected '_dataSaveAllowed' => boolean true
  protected '_isObjectNew' => null
  protected '_data' => 
    array
      empty
  protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean false
  protected '_origData' => null
  protected '_idFieldName' => string 'referencedpages_id' (length=18)
  protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
  protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
    array
      empty
  protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
    array
      empty
```

Here is my **Edit.php** code file, with the `getHeaderText` function:

```
<?php
class Dts_Allpages_Block_Adminhtml_Allpagesbackend_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'allpages';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_allpagesbackend';
        $this->_mode = 'edit';

        $this->_addButton('save_and_continue', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
                'onclick' => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
                'class' => 'save',
        ), -100);

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('allpages')->__('Save reference'));

        $this->_formScripts[] = "
                        function toggleEditor() {
                            if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('form_content') == null) {
                            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'edit_form');
                                } else {
                                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'edit_form');
                                    }
                                }

                        function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
                        }
                ";
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if (Mage::registry('allpages_data')  && Mage::registry('allpages_data')->getId()){
            return Mage::helper('allpages')->__('Edit reference');
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('allpages')->__('New reference');
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        if ($this->_blockGroup && $this->_controller && $this->_mode) {
            $this->setChild('form', $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'));
        }
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

And here is my **Form.php** file code:

```
<?php
class Dts_Allpages_Block_Adminhtml_Allpagesbackend_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $params = array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getdata())
        {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getdata();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getdata(null);
        }
        elseif (Mage::registry('allpages_data'))
        {
            $data = Mage::registry('allpages_data')->getdata();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array();
        }

//      $entireregistryArray = Mage::getRegistry();
//      var_dump($entireregistryArray);

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
                array(
                        'id' => 'edit_form',
                        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', $params),
                        'method' => 'post',
                        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                    )
                );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('allagesbackend_form', array(
                                'legend' =>Mage::helper('allpages')->__('References pages Information')
                            )
                    );

        $fieldset->addField('current_url', 'text', array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('allpages')->__('Url'),
                        'class'     => 'required-entry',
                        'required'  => true,
                        'name'      => 'current_url',
                        'note'      => Mage::helper('allpages')->__('The url of the reference.'),
                    )
            );

        $fieldset->addField('search_engine', 'text', array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('allpages')->__('Engine'),
                        'class'     => 'required-entry',
                        'required'  => true,
                        'name'      => 'search_engine',
                    )
            );

        $fieldset->addField('description', 'text', array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('allpages')->__('Description'),
                        'class'     => 'required-entry',
                        'required'  => true,
                        'name'      => 'description',
                    )
            );

        $form->setValues($data);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Just in case it helps, I'm using *CommerceBug* tool from AlanStorm.

**1st EDIT**
Here is a piece of my ActionController code, where I call the `Mage::register('allpages_date')` prior to the call to `renderLayout()` as suggested by @benmarks

```
public function editAction()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('referencedpages_id', null);
        $model = Mage::getModel('allpages/referencedpages');

        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
        }

        if ($model->getId() || $id == 0) {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
            if ($data) {
                $model->setData($data)->setId($id);
            }
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('allpages')->__('Referencedpages table does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }

        Mage::register('allpages_data', $model);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Found the error, on the `editAction()` on the first line, instead of `getParam('referencedpages_id', null)` should be `getParam('id', null)`. Thanks @benmarks to at least pointing me on the right place to look, I was looking only on the `Form.php` and the `Edit.php`

Comment: here `Mage::register('allpages_data', $model);` you choose `allpages_data` it is random or from any file name u choose?

Comment: Is a name I choose for my file structure

Comment: ohk, i get it, Why we use this? 

i mean can't we use session for this task?

 if yes, then  what is different between registry and session?

Comment: Sorry, can't answer that last comment, no longer testing Magento, nothing installed and the few things I had clear now are not so clear behind several months of lovely tsql code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't setting that registry key in your action controller prior to `renderLayout()` then it is not being set in a useful way for block rendering. Consider it like any other variable - there's no magic there.

Comment: Question edited. Added a piece of code from my actionController, where I'm calling the  `Mage::register()` before calling the `renderLayout()`, forgot to add this code, thanks.

Comment: Edited once again to add the `allpages_data` var_dump, I guess could be usefull too.

Comment: Found the error, on the `editAction()` on the first line, instead of `getParam('referencedpages_id', null)` should be `getParam('id', null)`. Thanks @benmarks to at least pointing me on the right place to look, I was looking only on the `Form.php` and the `Edit.php`.